# Ninject with asp.net mvc 5 controller and apicontroller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I have asp.net mvc controller and apicontroller. I trying to use ninject for controller and for apicontroller. And ninject works for controller but doesn't work for apicontroller.

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcAPI_demo.Models;

namespace MvcAPI_demo.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IReservationRepository _repository;

        public HomeController(IReservationRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        //
        // GET: /Home/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_repository.GetAll());
        }
}


using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;
using MvcAPI_demo.Models;

namespace MvcAPI_demo.Controllers
{
    public class WebApiController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly IReservationRepository _repository;

        public WebApiController()
        {
        }

        public WebApiController(IReservationRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Reservation> GetAllReservations()
        {
            return _repository.GetAll();
        }
}





using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcAPI_demo.Models;
using Ninject;

namespace MvcAPI_demo.Infrastructure
{
    public class NinjectDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        private readonly IKernel _kernel;

        public NinjectDependencyResolver()
        {
        }

        public NinjectDependencyResolver(IKernel kernel)
        {
            _kernel = kernel;
            AddBinding();
        }

        private void AddBinding()
        {
            _kernel.Bind<IReservationRepository>().To<NonPersistReservationRepository>().InSingletonScope();
        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            return _kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            return _kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
        }
    }
}
```

NinjectWebCommon.cs

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));


        }
```

when I try to  call ***/api/webapi*** is  requires a default constructor, if I make   a default constructor is not created new instance of a IReservationRepository. Regular MVC controller work correctly. How to make them work together?

Comment: **UPD** <br/>
To resolve this problem was used nuget package Ninject.MVC5 (not MVC3)  and to work with WebAPI I used Nuget package  Ninject.Web.WebApi Version 3.2.1  with new version (3.4.0) does not work. And bindings was included to the RegisterServices<br/><br/>
`private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<IReservationRepository>().To<NonPersistReservationRepository>().InSingletonScope();
        }  `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a different Nuget package for web API.

See [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Web.WebApi/)

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful. To resolve this problem I had to use Ninject.Web.WebApi Version 3.2.1, by default was installed 3.2.4